# Undefined Variable Error Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

El error es: **Undefined variable: prestadores (View: E:\CursoLaravel\sisMSP\resources\views\PMedicamentos\create.blade.php)**

Sucede al querer ingresar a la vista de create.blade para realizar el alta de un usuario. El codigo de aqui abajo es para que muestre en el formulario los prestadores de salud en un desplegable, los cuales estan cargados en su correspondiente tabla de la base de datos.

En el controller tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace SGP\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use sisMSP\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use sisMSP\Http\Requests\PMedicamentosFormRequest;
use App\PMedicamentos;
use DB;

class PMedicamentosController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

public function create()
    {
        $departamentos=DB::table('departamentos')->get();
        return view("PMedicamentos.create",["departamentos"=>$departamentos]);
        $medicamentosp=DB::table('medicamentos')->where('condicion','=','1')->get();
        return view("PMedicamentos.create",["medicamentos"=>$medicamentosp]);
        $prestadores=DB::table('prestador/seguro')->get();
        return view("PMedicamentos.create",["prestadores"=>$prestadores]);
        $laboratorios=DB::table('laboratorios')->get();
        return view("PMedicamentos.create",["laboratorios"=>$laboratorios]);
        $solicitud=DB::table('tipo de solicitud')->get();
        return view("PMedicamentos.create",["solicitud"=>$solicitud]);
    }
```

En el create.blade la parte que hace referencia a lo de arriba es lo siguiente:

```
@extends ('layouts.admin')
@section ('contenido')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <h3>Nuevo Paciente</h3>
            @if (count($errors)>0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{$error}}</li>
                @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
            {!!Form::open(array('url'=>'PMedicamentos','method'=>'POST','autocomplete'=>'off','files'=>'true'))!!}
            {{Form::token()}}

<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Prestador de Salud</label>
                <select name="Prestador_Seguro" class="form-control">
                    @foreach ($prestadores as $pre)
                       <option value="{{$pre->Nombre}}">{{$pre->Nombre}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Agradezco sus respuestas.

Saludos.

Comment: Siempre llamas a la misma vista pero pasas nombres de variables diferentes. Por ejemplo aca pasas la variable `departamentos` asi que obvio te genera error `$departamentos=DB::table('departamentos')->get(); return view("PMedicamentos.create", ["departamentos"=>$departamentos]);`

Comment: los nombres de tus tablas no deberían ser con espacios, considera ese detalle a futuro, también el detalle de poner en el nombre una diagonal

Comment: Laude. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Hay dos líneas que me parecen extrañas y son las que te menciona Aprendiz. Por favor, agrega las migraciones de esas tablas por favor o en caso de que no creaste una migración, adjunta la definición de ambas tablas. Prestadores y solicitudes.

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar, lastima que eliminaron la respuesta con la solución

Comment: @Laude puede ser así o con un método `compact()` pasando las propiedades separadas por comas y sería igual `compact($var, $var2, ....);`

Comment: @Laude había eliminado la respuesta, porque estoy de acuerdo con lo que dicen Aprendiz y Pak Lei Cong. Hay una inconsistencia en los nombres de las tablas que pueden generar comportamientos inesperados. Ahí la puse otra vez, pero te sugiro que revises lo que si te dice de las tablas

Comment: Ya les cambie de nombre, lo iba a hacer mas adelante pero estoy de acuerdo con ustedes, prefiero eso a seguir generando errores

Comment: ¿Son necesarias tantas consultas a la base de datos para una sola petición? ¿No están relacionados dichos modelos? Bueno, si es que son modelos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la función de tu controlador tienes muchos returns. Entonces el código se ejecuta hasta encontrar un return y sale de esa función, retornado la vista con una sola variable.

Prueba retornando solo una vez la vista junto con todas las variables:

```
public function create()
{
    $departamentos = DB::table('departamentos')->get();

    $medicamentosp = DB::table('medicamentos')->where('condicion','=','1')->get();

    $prestadores = DB::table('prestador/seguro')->get();

    $laboratorios = DB::table('laboratorios')->get();

    $solicitud = DB::table('tipo de solicitud')->get();

    return view('PMedicamentos.create', [
        "departamentos" => $departamentos,
        "medicamentos" => $medicamentosp,
        "prestadores" => $prestadores,
        "laboratorios" => $laboratorios,
        "solicitud" => $solicitud
    ]);
}
```